# Bounded linear operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Given T a bounded linear operator $T:X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces,

I'm trying to show that $\|T\|_*=\sup\{ \frac{\|Tx\|_Y}{\|x\|_X},x\neq0\}$  equals to $\sup\{\|T(x)\|_Y\,:\, \|x\|_X< 1\}$.

I can show that  $\|T\|_*=\sup\{\|T(x)\|_Y\,:\, \|x\|_X\le 1\}$, but I can't go further.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so what you can do is find an $x \in\overline{B_1(0)}$ that is $\epsilon >0$ close to the supremum. i.e.
$$\| Tx\| \geq \|T\| - \epsilon.$$
Then we can find $y \in B_1(0)$ such that $y = (1-\epsilon)x$ and so by linearity it follows that,
$$\| Ty\| \geq (1-\epsilon)(\|T\| - \epsilon)$$
and as $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we can conclude that,
$$\sup \{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1\} \leq \sup \{\|Tx\| : \|x\| < 1\}.$$
The other inequality should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Any $x_0$ such that $\|x_0\|_X=1$ can be approached by a sequence of elements in $\{x \in X : \|x\|_X < 1\}$. Since $x \mapsto \|T(x)\|_Y$ is a continuous function, you can approximate $\|T(x_0)\|$ arbitrarily closely with some $\|T(x)\|$ for $\|x\|_X < 1$.